# Running Tor on strange Wifi

Tags: tails

I would like to know if someone gets more privacy if connects to Tor using Tails but, connects to other wifi (example: neighbour wifi).

I mean: Tails --> password discovered wifi --> Tor -->...

What I would like to know is, if your VPN or Tor gets exposed, who is behind it? Because I suppose that what the attacker will see is the IP of not your wifi, but the other.

Is that correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: In the schema you have a wrong order. The Tor connection is terminated on the Tails system. Over the WiFi the communication is already encrypted by Tor and the destination IP address is hidden.

Answer (score 2):

If you use someone else's wifi and the ip gets exposed then it'll show their ip.
But keep in mind that mac address of connecting hardware can be used to trace your equipment, tails spoofs the mac,  making it harder (or impossible) to know if you used their connection.

Answer (score 2):

> What I would like to know is, if your VPN or Tor gets exposed, who is behind it? Because I suppose that what the attacker will see is the IP of not your wifi, but the other.

They would see your neighbors IP. But keep in mind that neighbors are always the first target if they believe the suspects wifi has been breached. Use a public wifi like starbucks etc.

Comment: This is a prudent advice. You have my up vote.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are careful about possibilities of relating of the access point to your activities (like living in the proximity of the AP) then you get additional layer of privacy.

In addition to the first two answers:

- More generally: Select a Wi-Fi which could hardly be connected to you (your activities).
- There could be other means of compromising your privacy like cameras in the proximity of the access point.
- The Wi-Fi devices communicating through the access point could possibly be fingerprinted on layer 2 regardless on the (generated) MAC address. There are smaller or bigger differences in the Wi-Fi device and driver implementations and the set of features implemented. This fingerprinting is possible but not commonly used. See for example this article: [Passive Data Link Layer 802.11 Wireless Device Driver Fingerprinting](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jfrankli/usenixsec06/usenixsec06driverfingerprinting.ps).

Answer (score 0):

It is almost certainly illegal to use a neighbor WIFI without their consent. If you go without their consent you are already in trouble. If you get their consent there is no advantage for you and maybe even some disadvantage because they can watch and time your communication albeit maybe in encrypted format. This is one unnecessary additional entity that can watch you. In addition as one of the other answers alluded to neighbors are always the first target if they believe the suspects WIFI has been breached. Now the best option as alluded to in one of other answers is a public WIFI far from your neighborhood. So to put it in a nutshell using neighbor WIFI is illegal and may make a criminal out of you if it is used without neighbor's consent and a disadvantage if used with neighbor consent.
The best option is a public WIFI far from your neighborhood. ***Do not put yourself in trouble.***